# Apply Clipping to Video in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, html5-video

I need to play the same video twice side by side. The video on the left should show the right half of the video and vice versa. So it will look like this:

[image]

The following HTML works in Firefox but not in Chrome (where it just ignores the clipping). I don't want to copy the frames out to Canvas because that will not be fast enough. Is there any way to cajole Chrome into clipping a video tag?

code:

```css
 #video1 {
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(0px, 1000px, 1000px, 150px);
   left: 0px;
 }
 #video2 {
   position: absolute;
   clip: rect(0px, 150px, 1000px, 0px);
   left: 300px;
 }
```

```html
<video id="video1" width="300px" controls loop autoplay>
  <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
<video id="video2" width="300px" controls loop autoplay mute>
  <source src="http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: (Curious) Canvas is fast enough.. what makes you say it isn't?

Comment: K3N My video is actually 1080p and I'm  playing it twice. Canvas approach adds enough overhead to make it not smooth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS `clip` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip) and has been removed from the web standard.

> This feature has been removed from the Web standards. Though some
> browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped.
> Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may
> break at any time.

You can use `clip-path` instead - it has to be prefixed in Chrome/Opera:

```css
#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#video1 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 0 0 150px);
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 150px);
  left: -150px;
}
#video2 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0 150px 0 0);
  clip-path: inset(0 150px 0 0);
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id=wrapper>
  <video id="video1" width="300px" muted controls loop autoplay>
    <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <video id="video2" width="300px" muted controls loop autoplay mute>
    <source src="https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</div>
```

Though it seem that this does not work properly in Firefox so you might have to combine the old with the new for them to work (or wrap the video elements in a container div that is then clipped using `overflow:hidden`).

###Alternative Canvas Solution

An alternative route can be to use canvas (which is fast enough..) which also allow you to frame-accurately synchronize the two half (which you cannot do using two video sources) as well as using just a single stream instead of two (in this case):

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
    video = document.createElement("video");

video.oncanplay = draw;
video.loop = video.autoplay = video.muted = true;
video.src = "https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/240/big_buck_bunny_240p_50mb.mp4";

ctx.fillText("Loading video...", 20, 20);

function draw() {
  var vw = video.videoWidth>>1;                              // half width
  var vh = video.videoHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, vw, vh, 150, 0, 150, c.height); // draw left half to the right
  ctx.drawImage(video, vw, 0, vw, vh, 0, 0, 150, c.height);  // draw right half to the left
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
```

```html
<canvas id=c width=300 height=220></canvas>
```